# Oracle Fusion Middleware (SOA Suite) 2-way SSL Outbound SOAP Connection

Tags: ssl, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware

I'm trying to set up a 2-way SSL connection to an external web service using Oracle Fusion Middleware (a.k.a. SOA Suite). I've googled and even bing'ed my brains out and have found lots of good documentation on creating the JKS, and even some details on adding `<property name="oracle.soa.two.way.ssl.enabled">true</property>` to the `binding.ws` element in the composite's XML (all of which I've done). What I haven't found/figured out is how to explicitly state what alias from the JKS to use for that particular connection. This is especially problematic because depending on some key parameters, I need to use one cert rather than another one when establishing that connection (same endpoint, have to pick from 2 different certs). How/Where do I set this up? Is it in BPEL, in the composite? etc.

I've seen code on how to do this in straight Java, but given the visual nature of BPEL and the Composite, I don't know how to tell the system to use a specific key from a key store.

Comment: We were informed by Oracle technical support that this was not something that could be accomplished with Oracle SOA Suite. We wound up having to go a different route with authenticating our service calls.That said, if someone were to find a way (even if that's with an upgrade to the SOA Suite version), that'd be great to know.